# Infinite quotients of surface groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $S_g$ be the fundamental group of a genus $g$ surface.  What are the possible infinite quotients of $S_g$?  Are they all free?

Comment: It maps onto the free group on 2 generators (if $g\ge 2$), so on every 2-generated group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like any nonelementary hyperbolic group, $\pi_1(S_g)$ is an [SQ-universal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQ-universal_group), which means that every countable group can be embedded in some quotient of $\pi_1(S_g)$. So no, not every quotient of $\pi_1(S_g)$ is free.